# GoogleAnalytics API Audience > Technology > Network > Service Provider

Tags: google-analytics-api

There is a proliferation of LeadFeeder, WhoisVisiting, Leady, LeadFuse, LeadForensics type sites.

The founder of LeadFeeder wrote about it here: https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/09/using-google-analytics-with-leadfeeder.html.

They all use the Google Analytics API to gather the Audience > Technology > Network > Service Provider field.

For the life of me I can't find this in the API documentation.

I went through every core Dimension I could find here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

The only other thing I can think of is that maybe the Network Audience is only available to Google Analytics 360 Premium?

I've scoured the API documentation and Googled it into the ground.

Not much code to show... unless you know the right API function to call... which I can't figure out!

Answer (score 1):

It's called [networkLocation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network&jump=ga_networklocation) in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I finally ended up finding a reference to it here too:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/pdoZrbbC5RQ